# "Unable to connect" when trying to reach a Docker container

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to learn Docker, but I cant even get started :(

I made an microservice which just returns "test" if you call it. If I run `java -jar test.jar` and I go to `localhost:8080`, the browser displays the expected result:

[image]

But if I use Docker to deploy that JAR I can't access the page:

[image]

This is my `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

ARG JAR_FILE=test.jar
ARG PORT=8080

EXPOSE ${PORT}

VOLUME /tmp
ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
```

### `docker build -t test .`

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon   16.2MB
Step 1/7 : FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
 ---> 5801f7d008e5
Step 2/7 : ARG JAR_FILE=test.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 7095632eee4a
Step 3/7 : ARG PORT=8080
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4a1351be9f66
Step 4/7 : EXPOSE ${PORT}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6f7958533a34
Step 5/7 : VOLUME /tmp
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 6bafa2fa82cf
Step 6/7 : ADD ${JAR_FILE} app.jar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 2dc3da720820
Step 7/7 : ENTRYPOINT ["java","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-jar","/app.jar"]
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 60348d53cf97
Successfully built 60348d53cf97
Successfully tagged test:latest
```

### `docker run test -p 8080:8080`

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.4.RELEASE)

2018-09-03 18:53:26.595  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Starting DemoApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on 81a95eb3474a with PID 1 (/app.jar started by root in /)
2018-09-03 18:53:26.599  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-09-03 18:53:26.669  INFO 1 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@12f40c25: startup date [Mon Sep 03 18:53:26 GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-03 18:53:28.215  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-09-03 18:53:28.253  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.253  INFO 1 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
2018-09-03 18:53:28.272  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64/server:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/lib/amd64:/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8-openjdk/jre/../lib/amd64:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.355  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-09-03 18:53:28.356  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1691 ms
2018-09-03 18:53:28.422  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.426  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.427  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.427  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.427  INFO 1 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.589  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.833  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@12f40c25: startup date [Mon Sep 03 18:53:26 GMT 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-09-03 18:53:28.944  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.String com.example.demo.NewRestController.getTEst()
2018-09-03 18:53:28.949  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-09-03 18:53:28.950  INFO 1 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-09-03 18:53:28.977  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-03 18:53:28.977  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-09-03 18:53:29.140  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-09-03 18:53:29.191  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2018-09-03 18:53:29.195  INFO 1 --- [           main] com.example.demo.DemoApplication         : Started DemoApplication in 3.008 seconds (JVM running for 3.491)
```

### `docker ps`

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
81a95eb3474a        test                "java -Djava.securit…"   2 minutes ago       Up 2 minutes        8080/tcp            happy_feynman
```

I've been stuck on this for over a day and I can't wrap my head around it. What should I do?

Comment: I'm not that familiar with java, but try to enter your container and see if it works from within.
> docker exec happy_feynman bash

Comment: The port and IP you need to use in order to reach your container are probably different from `localhost:8080`. See the [documentation for `docker port`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/port/).

Comment: not really... if the container is running on his machine localhost is fine, and the port 8080 is the one he exposed, so it's fine. I thought about a conflict with your local 8080, but apparently, the container started so I guess nobody was using your local 8080. Otherwise, your container wouldn't have started.

Comment: @grooveplex docker port elegant_jang
8080/tcp -> 0.0.0.0:8080

Comment: @sebagomez $ docker exec elegant_jang bash                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                OCI runtime exec failed: exec failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"bash\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown

Comment: what are the contents of `server.xml`?

Comment: @AlexKarshin im using java spring boot i dont have a server.xml, i didnt change any configurations. not even the port

Comment: Okay, what are the contents of `application.properties`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change `docker run test -p 8080:8080` to `docker run -p 8080:8080 test` as your current syntax instead of exposing port on `localhost` is passing `-p 8080:8080` as argument to your program. You can see that in `docker ps`, where under ports you have only `8080/tcp`, which means that your port is exposed inside docker network - not mapped to host. More info: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/

Comment: thank you that works! im sorry that somebody downvoted your answer but it worked thanks!